# awk regexp when not match

Tags: awk

I got some help before here to construct a regexp that would match any lines that started with ":" then anything, then a "(" and after that anything, but it could not end with a ")"

The regexp I used was this:

```
/:.+ \(.[^)]*$/
```

It seemes to work reasonably well. I had this input lines:

```
:web_application_settings (
:isakmp.phase1_DH_groups (
:ike_p1 (
:ike_p1_dh_grp (ReferenceObject
:isakmpkeymanager (lalalal)
```

And the output was only: :ike_p1_dh_grp (ReferenceObject

But then I happened to add the line:

```
:isakmpkeymanager ()
```

This shouldnt match, but it does, which I think is strange. What did I miss in the regexp that allowed this line that ends with a ")" to still match, when I use Do not match: [^)] followed by start to allow it to not match and then end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` after the `\(` allows any single arbitrary character - including `)` - immediately after the opening parenthesis. If that's not what you want to say, take it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk '/:.+ \([^)]+$/' File
```

#### What went wrong

Let's look at the original regex, `/:.+ \(.[^)]*$/`, one step at a time:

1. `:` meaning a single colon
2. `.+` meaning *one or more* of any character.  (`+` means *one or more*.)
3. meaning *one* blank
4. `\(` meaning *one* open parens
5. `.` meaning *one* of any character
6. `[^)]*` meaning *zero or more* of any character except close parens.  (`*` means *zero or more*.)
7. `$` meaning the end of the line.

The problem was step 5 which can match a `)`.  In the revised regex, this was eliminated and `[^)]*` was replaced with `[^)]+`.